# AWS MSK: join broker back to the cluster after simulated outage

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-msk

In attempts to simulate a broker outage in msk cluster, I've detachhed the network interface of the broker and now I'm unable to reattach it.

Looking through the docs, this is might be something that the HEALING operation might resolve. I was wondering of there is a way to manully trigger such operation or is there another way of adding the broker back to the cluster?